# Run JavaScript After DataBind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ASP.Net Repeater control with a Table inside it.  Is it possible to run a JavaScript function directly AFTER I call `MyRepeater.DataBind()`?  I've been trying different things, but nothing is triggering the JavaScript function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a solution, not sure it's the cleanest way to do it, but for my application's context it works:

I ran the javascript code after a partial postback using: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest();`

Again, not the cleanest but suits the needs I have.

Thanks for all your input

Answer (score 2):

Databinding occurs on the server in a postback as part of the [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) process. In other words, excluding partial-postbadks, at the time this happens any existing DOM in the browser is destroyed. A whole new page is constructed on the server and transmitted to the browser, so that a new DOM can be built and rendered.

What all that means is that you want to think in terms of running your javascript in the page's onload event. One way to make this happen is using the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can be called from server side by using RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock methods.

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Register-clientside-startup-script-from-serverside-code-286.php

Answer (score 1):

No. The javascript isn't even going to render and run until the code-behind has executed and the page delivered to the client. So it won't matter if adding the script is the first thing you do in the code-behind or the last thing you do (or directly after the `DataBind()`).

When using the [ClientScriptManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx), look at your code behind and you'll see the dynamic javascript is added just before the ending `</form>` tag (although it still may be possible to accomplish what you want to do, just with a different approach).